# Can I get a list of which publishers are publishing to RabbitMQ exchanges from the RabbitMQ HTTP API?

Tags: rabbitmq

We're building a system which maps relationships between publishers -> rabbitMQ (exchanges, queues etc) and consumers.

We can get exchanges, queues and consumers directly from the RabbitMQ HTTP API, but we're trying to find a way to work out who is publishing, and to what exchange.

The closest I can seem to get is using 'channels' to map what IPs are connected to vhosts, but I can't find a way to get a direct relationship between publishers and exchanges from the API. For all I know it's not possible at all, but thought it was worth a question...

Answer (score 2):

Actually, how to define a `Publisher` is not clear in differrent Messaging protocols. I guess RabbitMQ will not maintain a `Publisher` list in server.

From [RabbitMQ official document](https://www.rabbitmq.com/publishers.html#terminology):

> The term "publisher" means different things in different contexts. In general in messaging a publisher (also called "producer") is an application (or application instance) that publishes (produces) messages. The same application can also consume messages and thus be a consumer at the same time.

I think `Publisher == Channel` in AMQP-0-9-1 protocol, `Publiseher == Connection` in STOMP protocol and so on.